# My top level menu items do not work - TWITTER Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a drop down menu with bootstrap, here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ajfbqfej/

```
<nav id="navvy" class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
                    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex8-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex8-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                                    <li class=" dropdown">
                                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" href="#">Capabilities</a>

                                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                                <li><a href="http://www.forstertool.com/Capabilities/Precision-Machining">Precision Machining</a></li>

                                                <li><a href="http://www.forstertool.com/Capabilities/CNC-Turning">CNC Turning</a></li>

                                                <li><a href="http://www.forstertool.com/Capabilities/Swiss-Screw-Machining">Swiss Screw Machining</a></li>

                                                <li><a href="http://www.forstertool.com/Capabilities/Medical-Machining">Medical Machining</a></li>

                                                <li><a href="http://www.forstertool.com/Capabilities/CNC-Milling">CNC Milling</a></li>

                                                <li><a href="http://www.forstertool.com/Capabilities/Secondary-Operations">Secondary Operations</a></li>

                                                </ul>

                                    </li>

                                    <li class=" dropdown">
                                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" href="#">Products</a>

                                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                                <li><a href="http://www.forstertool.com/Products/Miniature-Parts">Miniature Parts</a></li>

                                                <li><a href="http://www.forstertool.com/Products/Nozzles">Nozzles</a></li>

                                                <li><a href="http://www.forstertool.com/Products/Bike-Chain-Link">Bike Chain Link</a></li>

                                                <li><a href="http://www.forstertool.com/Products/Shafts">Shafts</a></li>

                                                <li><a href="http://www.forstertool.com/Products/Fasteners-Screws">Fasteners & Screws</a></li>

                                                <li><a href="http://www.forstertool.com/Products/Brackets-Plates-Mounts">Brackets, Plates & Mounts</a></li>

                                                <li><a href="http://www.forstertool.com/Products/Valves">Valves</a></li>

                                                </ul>

                                    </li>

                                    <li class=" dropdown">
                                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" href="#">Material Specialties</a>

                                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                                <li><a href="http://www.forstertool.com/Material-Specialties/Stainless-Steel">Stainless Steel</a></li>

                                                <li><a href="http://www.forstertool.com/Material-Specialties/Plastic">Plastic</a></li>

                                                <li><a href="http://www.forstertool.com/Material-Specialties/Aluminum">Aluminum</a></li>

                                                <li><a href="http://www.forstertool.com/Material-Specialties/Steel">Steel</a></li>

                                                <li><a href="http://www.forstertool.com/Material-Specialties/Brass">Brass</a></li>

                                                <li><a href="http://www.forstertool.com/Material-Specialties/Hastelloy">Hastelloy</a></li>

                                                <li><a href="http://www.forstertool.com/Material-Specialties/Monel">Monel </a></li>

                                                <li><a href="http://www.forstertool.com/Material-Specialties/Titanium">Titanium</a></li>

                                                </ul>

                                    </li>

                                    <li class=" dropdown">
                                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" href="http://www.forstertool.com/About">About</a>

                                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                                <li><a href="http://www.forstertool.com/Quality-Assurance">Quality Assurance</a></li>

                                                <li><a href="http://www.forstertool.com/Equipment">Equipment</a></li>

                                                <li><a href="http://www.forstertool.com/Industries-Served">Industries Served</a></li>

                                                </ul>

                                    </li>

                                    <li class=" ">
                                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" href="http://www.forstertool.com/Gallery">Gallery</a>

                                    </li>

                                    <li class=" dropdown">
                                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" href="http://www.forstertool.com/Resources">Resources</a>

                                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                                <li><a href="http://www.forstertool.com/Resources/Latest-News">Latest News</a></li>

                                                </ul>

                                    </li>

                                    <li class=" dropdown">
                                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" href="http://www.forstertool.com/Contact-Us">Contact Us</a>

                                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                                <li><a href="http://www.forstertool.com/Contact-Us/Careers">Careers</a></li>

                                                <li><a href="http://www.forstertool.com/Contact-Us/RFQ">RFQ</a></li>

                                                </ul>

                                    </li>

                                    <li class=" ">
                                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" href="http://www.forstertool.com/Glossary">Glossary</a>

                                    </li>

                                    <li class=" ">
                                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" href="http://www.forstertool.com/Resources/Forster-Blog">Blog</a>

                                    </li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                </nav>
```

The top level items are not clickable, can anyone see what I might be doing wrong?  Otherwise it works great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - for me I just had to remove the data-toggle attribute from my anchors... weird!